# turtlebot not publishing tf

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I've a problem with turtlebot....It is not publishing the transform between any part of the robot, actually any transform at all!!!

I've runed:

```
rosrun tf tf_monitor
```

and what i get is:

```
Frames:

All Broadcasters:

RESULTS: for all Frames

Frames:
```

Can somebody give me a hint on what to do??

Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36414/turtlebot-not-publishing-tf/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-13**:
Please give more information, otherwise it's really hard to help. 1) On which computer are you running tf_monitor? That one on the turtlebot? 2) How is your turtlebot started up? What does `rosnode list` show?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-06-13**:
could we get a rostopic list? Maybe a bag file of recorded odometry? Is this an actual turtlebot (silly question, but a lot of robots use turtlebot code to run although they aren't turtlebots)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've sovled it. I've chagned the name of the turtlebot-laptop  in the workstation to turtlebot, the same the on on the robot has an now i get the tf in the workstation.

---

Originally posted by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) with karma: 318 on 2012-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0